# Task.Factory.StartNew not starting?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am trying to go out to a gateway, get data then return on the UI thread . The ContinueWith runs, but the Gateway never does??

```
ILogonResult result;

Task.Factory
.StartNew(() =>
    {
        result = Gateway.Authenticate(a, b);
    })
.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        DoSomeUI(result);
    }
);
```

Comment: The context is in a wrong place here, it should be a parameter in `ContinueWith`...

Comment: I see a lot of problems here, but there's not really enough info to answer your question.  1) You shouldn't be setting a `result` variable in the task, you should be returning the result; the continuation can then read the value from `task.Result`. 2) Your `fromUIContext` is in the wrong place; you want it as the second argument to `ContinueWith` to make the continuation run in the UI thread.  `DoSomeUI` also should be given the result of the task as a parameter.  Also, what is the type of `Result`?  Without knowing that it's hard to say what could be going on with `Authenticate`.

Comment: Also, I'm going to use my psychic debugging techinques to say that `result` is a `Task<T>`, and your starting a task that starts a task; it's completed when you finish starting the task, not when the task that it started actually completes, which is why the continuation seems to run right away.

Comment: @servy Updated as requested

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com That's not particularly helpful.  What's an `ILogonResult`?  Does it represent the asynchronous completion of the authentication, or does it contain the actual results of the authentication?

Comment: Your `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` does nothing useful in this code.

Comment: @Servy it represents the result of the call to the service. A payload.

Comment: How are you verifying that `Gateway.Authenticate` didn't run.  Are you just noticing that `result` is null?  If `Authenticate` throws an exception, `result` will be null, but the continuation will run.

Comment: @MATT In the example above I stripped it down to the simplest parts to keep the question clean.

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com, that doesn't answer the question I'm asking you: how are you determining that the code didn't run--because when I use your code with dummy implementations, it *does* run `Authenticate`.

Comment: When I run it on an iPhone the code never executes. (Using Mono, C#4.5)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a go at this,  it seems you are just wishing to execute the Gateway.Authenticate method and return that result type to a method that updates your UI.

```
Task.Factory
.StartNew(() =>
{
    return Gateway.Authenticate(a, b);
})
.ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    if (t.Exception == null)
    {
       DoSomeUI(t.Result);
    }else{
       //Handle Exception Message
    }
}
);
```

Comment: While this is certainly a better practice way of doing this, as I described in my comment to the question itself, it is functionally identical.  If the code in the OP isn't working then this won't work either.

Comment: I don't think this is identical, due to the fact I am acting upon the result property of the Task parameter which means its going to attempt to run the task and get a result before the continue with can happen.  In the OP he just sets the result in the start new but continuewith isn't using any properties of the Task parameter so it  will go ahead and fire.  Result is just a variable and while its not initialized it has a type.  Continuewith will just see it call  that method with a null result passed along.

Comment: It's a call to `ContinueWith`, not a second call to `StartNew`.  The continuation won't start running until the task it is continuing has completed execution.  **That's the whole point of a continuation; if it ran before the task it was continuing was done it wouldn't serve any purpose at all!**  It doesn't matter whether it uses any properties of the task it continues or not.

Comment: I misunderstood after doing some reading I understand what your saying, I had some confusion on my understanding of what as going on.